# How to first login using sudo and then run rest of Unix Shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on Automating deployment script for which I have to run all steps as sudo user, when I try to sudo first in my script like below it prompt me for password and then rest of script doesn't execute, when i exit sudo then only it executes.

```
"sudo -u username bash"
```

Please help me how to achieve this or I have to first login using sudo and then only run my script ?

Comment: `sudo -u username bash` will start a new bash shell as the specified user. If you don't want a new shell, why do this?

Comment: thanks I was not aware of bash will create new shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead just run the script as sudo.

```
sudo sh ./script.sh
```

This way the entire script would run as a sudo user, and it would prompt only for once.

If you want to still use `sudo -u` you can use it like this, instead of:

```
sudo -u username bash
```

You can do:

```
sudo -u username sh ./script.sh
```